# foreach cross checking IP's and echo'ing matches

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if $userinfo[host] (a list of ip addresses) has ANY matches in visitors.txt file. If it is, echo the matching string(s)

Nothing seems to be echo'ed. No errors either.

Here is the basic txt file

```
  208.54.22.144|1355385350
  208.54.14.235|1355386649
  69.151.178.16|1355386296
```

(EDITED STRING)

```
$ips = file_get_contents('visitors.txt');
$ip_regex = '/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/';
foreach ($ips as $check){
preg_match($ip_regex, $check, $current_ip);
if ((strpos($userinfo['host'],$current_ip[0]) !== false)) {
echo $userinfo['host'];
}
}
```

Comment: 1. `var_dump($userinfo[host]);` 2. `host` should be enclosed in quotes (as long as it's a string)

Comment: Given that PHP should be *screaming* at you about point number two that zerkms brought up, you probably also want to make sure `error_reporting` is cranked all the way up and you're either logging or displaying errors.

Comment: edited (see above). Unfortunately, still nothing coming out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you are checking for the IP, however, the way you have it now are comparing more than just the IP, for example say my IP is 127.0.0.1 and in the visitor.txt file I had a valid entry like 127.0.0.1 | 123456. In your for each loop it would look like this:

if(127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|123456)....

You can try to compare just the IP using a regex to split out just the IP from the current line of text. For example:

```
$ips = file("visitors.txt");
echo "You are hosted at: ".$userinfo['host']."<br />";
$ip_regex = '/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/';
foreach ($ips as $check) {
    preg_match($ip_regex, $check, $current_ip);
    if ((strpos($userinfo['host'],$current_ip[0]) !== false)) {
        echo $userinfo['host'];
    }

}
```

Comment: See edited string above Chris. I'm now getting 
(Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [path]/mobilecheck.php on line 4). Is it the regex?

Comment: I think what you have there works fine Chris. I just need to figure out now why $userinfo['host'] isnt spitting out ALL the ip's.

Comment: that did the job. Tremendous thanks for the help, I learned alot with this stretch!

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

```
<?php
$ips = file_get_contents('test.txt');
if(strpos($ips, $userinfo['host']) !== FALSE)
{
  echo $userinfo['host'];
}
?>
```

Comment: agH! nothing. Could the listing formats be the issue?

$userinfo['host'] puts out like this: 71.52.67.94107.33.246.6470.196.135.6598.197.129.23498.196

while visitors.txt is listed in the format (see first post)

Comment: actually im not sure how it could be that, as it should be checking each ip individually and cycle through the rest